# I'm having problems in Roblox Lua script. I want to script it so the inventory is save upon death. Any tips?

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to write a script so that when a player dies the stuff in the inventory isn't gone. This is my current script, any pointers or tips on how to accomplish this? I've written it as a local and a server script and it's in the workspace, still no luck

```
local Inventory = {}

local function Spawned(Char)
    local Plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Char)
    for i,v in pairs(Inventory[Plr]) do
        if Plr['Backpack']:findFirstChild(v.Name) then
            Plr['Backpack'][v.Name]:Destroy()
        end
        v.Parent = Plr['Backpack']  
    end
    Inventory[Plr] = {}
    Char:WaitForChild('Humanoid').Died:connect(function()
        for i,v in pairs({Plr['Backpack'], Char}) do
            for ii,vv in pairs(v:GetChildren()) do
                if vv:IsA('Tool') then
                    table.insert(Inventory[Plr], vv:Clone())
                     vv:Destroy()
                end
            end
         end
     end)
 end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(Plr)
    Inventory[Plr] = {}
    local Char = Plr.Character or Plr.CharacterAdded:wait()
    Spawned(Char)
    Plr.CharacterAdded:connect(Spawned)
end)
```

Comment: What is the issue with the code?

Comment: My issue is no matter what I Change the the items still disappear when a player dies. The items are in replicated storage, when a player buys one it is now in his backpack and StarterGear, but maybe im not calling it right.

Comment: I want to make it to where when a player dies, the items in the inventory stay, not disappear to where the player has to re buy them.

Answer (score 1):

Put the items you want to persist over dying in Player.StarterGear

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways you could store a players inventory. I'll show a couple below so you can see them.

## 1. Storing The Weapons In StarterGear

As Coordinate Newton said, once the player buys a weapon instead of placing it in only the backpack you could also put it into their .StarterGear folder and this means that every time they spawn the tools will automatically be placed inside their new backpack. This is very simple to do as you only need to clone the weapons into:

```
game.Players.LocalPlayer.StarterGear
```

as well as the players backpack. You mentioned in the your comment that you have already tried this but that it didn't work but I'm afraid I can't think of a reason for it not working unfortunately.

## 2. Using IntValue's as Global Variables

If that can't be used then another way is to create a new IntValue instance every time a weapons is bought and destroying it if the weapon is removed. If you named the IntValue the name of the weapon the player has then you can use to code to find that weapon in replicated storage if it's stored there.

For example the following code, if put into a local script, would create a folder to store the IntValues in and then every time the player respawns the code will run through all those IntValues getting the names and placing the corresponding weapon into the players backpack.

```
game.Players.LocalPlayer.CharacterAdded:Connect(function()
    local Children = Storage:GetChildren()
    if #Children > 0 then --If there are stored weapons
        for _, child in pairs(Children) do
            -- Below: Clone the weapon from Replicated Storage using the name from the IntValue
            local WeaponClone = game.ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild(tostring(child.Name)):Clone()
            WeaponClone.Parent = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Backpack
        end
    end
end)

local Storage = Instance.new("Folder") --Folder to store current weapons in
Storage.Name = "BoughtWeapons"
Storage.Parent = game.Player.LocalPlayer
```

I've also made two functions that you can call to create and destroy an IntValue respectively.

```
local function WeaponBought(WeaponName)
    local WeaponSave = Instance.new("IntValue")
    WeaponSave.Name = WeaponName
    WeaponSave.Parent = game.Players.LocalPlayer.BoughtWeapons
end

local function WeaponRemoved(WeaponName)
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.BoughtWeapons:FindFirstChild(WeaponName):Destroy()
end
```

You can place these two functions in any local script, they don't have to be with the other main code. All you need to do is pass the name of the weapon the players has to the function, for example:

```
WeaponBought("GravityCoil")
```

This will create an IntValue inside the folder with the name "GravityCoil" to be used when the player respawns. This isn't as handy as simply using the StarterGear folder but if for some reason you can't then this is a good second option.

A slight problem with this solution is that it will require weapons to be stored in replicated storage where exploiters can very easily get to them without having to buy them. Unfortunately this is just a problem that comes with using local scripts to do this.

## Your Code

I'm pretty sure that the reason your code isn't working as intended is because, as far as I understand, the backpack of the player has already been cleared by the time Humanoid.Died fires and therefore you will be unable to get a list of what weapons the player had.

I hope this helps with what you're trying to do even if this is not exactly what you asked for.